# android preference activity

Tags: android, android-activity, preference

I have a preference activity and want that if one of its items is clicked it will start a background work and show a nice progress bar in foreground until the background task finishes. how to do it???

Code writtenis:

```
 public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
  showProgressDialog();
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    doSomething();
    hideProgressDialog();
   }       //Runnable.run()
  }).start();
  return false;
 }
});
```

But the above code is not showing progress dialog. and ANR error occurs.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included "Implements Runnable" at the start of the class, where you also implemented OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener?

Comment: When titling questions I would recommend focusing on the actual problem.  For instance, on this question I would have titled it "ProgressDialog not showing", or something like that.  Your preference activity likely has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code in your activity class:

```
// Need handler for callbacks to UI Threads
    // For background operations
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create Runnable for posting results
    final Runnable mUpdateDone = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            progDialog.hide();      
            // Do your task here what you want after the background task is finished.           
        }
    };
```

Write following code in onPreferenceClick:

```
progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AddPhoto.this, "", "Uploading Photo...");
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    // Start your task here.....                                                        
                    mHandler.post(mUpdateDone);
                }
                }.start();
```

Let me know if doesn't work for you!

Comment: thanks. but it is not working. Progress dialog is displayed, not spinning after start of background task. ANR Force close window is showing.

Comment: Just make sure that your BACKGROUND TASK is not producing ANR Force close.

It quite seems that `doSomething();` is going to produce the error.
Have you gone through Log Cat?
Paste the task's code you are performing in background.

Comment: thanks. i corrected the error. the error throws because of background service (doSomething). i have created a new thread in service. Now its working fine. thanks.

Comment: Hi Karthika, if you found the answer helpful kindly tick it as correct answer, thanks, Guru

Answer (score 1):

I have not implemented a progress dialog yet (plan to later today), but this [example](http://huuah.com/android-progress-bar-and-thread-updating/) looks like a good one.  I plan to use it myself.  I note that it does a number of things that your code does not.